# Can you choose same spell twice from different sources?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, warlock, spellcasting, racial-traits

I am optimizing my Warlock character now and wanted to pick new UA (for now) Hexblood race (detailed in [this](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/gothic-lineages) Unearthed Arcana article). I will get a free *hex* once per long rest as racial trait.

I'm also looking to a Fey Touched feat. It says I can pick 1 enchantment spell of my choice. So can I pick another *hex* through this feat and cast it without spell slot, so I have 2 free hexes per long rest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, you can learn the same spell more than once if it is from different sources.

In the case you mention, you'd get *hex* as a racial spell and *hex* as a special spell from a feat. This same logic applies when learning spells from multiple classes: you can learn, for example, *fire bolt* both as a wizard cantrip and as an artificer cantrip.

Most times it won't make any difference: the spell works regardless of its source, although it would use the spellcasting ability tied to it when making a spell attack or using a spell save DC. (*hex* does not take the spellcasting ability into account; however, if for some reason it mattered, learning it as a warlock would use Charisma, and if learned as a spell for Fey Touched would use the ability score increased by the feat).
The only time the source of your spell matters is when a feature or trait (of any kind) tells you that you can do something special when casting a "category" spell. For example, an Artillerist Artificer's 5th level feature can give them an extra d8 to any damaging artificer cantrip they cast trhough a special focus; this bonus would not apply if they cast a wizard spell (a spell learned through the wizard class) or a spell learned through a racial feature or feat, because *even though the spell is on the artificer list, they'd not know that spell as an artificer spell*.

In your case it probably will not matter: you'd get two castings of *hex* without a spell slot each day, and — because it is the Fey Touched feat — you can cast it with your Pact Magic spell slots, even though it is not considered a warlock spell for you for features that ask you to cast a warlock spell.

Comment: As unusual and counterintuitive as this answer sounds, it makes sense from a lore perspective (druids and wizards don't cast the same spell the same way) even if it doesn't usually have a mechanical benefit to do so. An example (contrived, admittedly) where it could have a mechanical difference would be Druid 18 / Paladin 2. If cure wounds was learned as a paladin spell, a wild shaped druid wouldn't be able to cast it because it's not a druid spell in that circumstance.

Comment: @MirrorImage You just hit me with the most obvious thing I did not take into accout for this kind of difference: spellcasting ability!

Comment: @Nick The answer received three downvotes while the question was closed for "needs details or clarity".

Comment: I was about to comment that a racial/feat sourced spell like that is usually limited in the slot level it's cast at (see tiefling or magic initiate) but funnily enough, neither the UA race nor the feat from Tasha's explicitly says the spell is cast at a given level, just that you get a once-per-long rest freebie.

Comment: @MissMisinformation The general rule is that a spell is cast at its lowest level possible when it comes to innate magic or similar features/traits, similarly to how Innate Spellcasting works in the Monster Manual. But yes, I agree that the wording seems to have become less detailed in more recent printings than the Player's Handbook.